# MacOS: Args are missing when running swift app using system(..) api from system daemon

Tags: c++, swift, macos, sh, daemon

I'm developing using Xcode swift ui app and c++ program which interacts with the app on macOS version 11.2.1.

The app is installed to `/Application/myApp`

When my c++ programs starts, it executes the app using system(..) api with 3 arguments:
`system("open -n -a /Application/myApp --args arg1 arg2 arg3");`

It all works well when I run my c++ program from xcode/terminal, the app is executed and receives the 3 arguments.

But when I run my c++ program as system daemon (root) the app is executed only without the 3 arguments.

Any ideas why arguments are not passed to my app when `system("open -n -a /Application/myApp --args arg1 arg2 arg3")` is invoked from a program running as system daemon and how can I fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: How sure are you that your C++ app is actually doing the call with the args? Logging? Because there's nothing magical about it running as a system daemon that is going to change that kind of behavior. But your program might not be getting the arguments properly.

Comment: 100% sure, App's log proves it was executed without the args.

Comment: Are you logging your server program's call? I have no doubt you're right -- that the app is being called incorrectly. But I think it's your C++ program with a bug. I think you're C++ program depends on an env var that isn't being set, for instance, or some other condition that is different when being run as a service. That's not a problem with the system() call or anything -- it's your program running in a different way is then deciding to call your app differently.

Comment: If `/Application/myApp` is an executable, why would you launch it with `open`? I would try a minimal `int main() { system(...); }` program that you run as a regular program (not a daemon) to test. I also wonder if `open` is an executable on macOS, or if it is a shell built-in.